# Facebook Auto-Hyperlinking on Android?

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

Here's an interesting one; I'm writing a JSFiddle for a friend in order to illustrate using a `:before 'content'` CSS rule so as to avoid using two background images and thus hindering loadtime and reaction time. But I'm out of the house, so I'm Fiddling on my Nexus 7.

http://jsfiddle.net/kTMe8/2/ (Please disregard my quick-and-dirty solution, I'm just illustrating the point in as few loc as possible)

To the best of my knowledge, this Fiddle should work as expected on a proper computer, but when I click on the .icon to see if I can fake a 'hover' action from my tab, it redirects the page to Facebook's mobile site.

Wuuuut.

There's no linking code in there as far as I can tell -- it's, like, twenty lines *max* of inactive HTML and CSS. Is this an Android builtin, and if so, how do I disable it on sites I deploy? What is going on?!

Stats:

- Stock Android 4.2.(?)
- Chrome Beta Browser (Suspicious...?)

Comment: Can you clarify where this is reproducing - in Chrome for Android or the Android Stock Browser (the blue globe icon)?

Tested on Android 4.2 presumably.

Comment: It was in Chrome for Android (4.2), yep!

Comment: Update: This was apparently a feature/bug that has been updated/resolved.